# Python main method options

Tags: python, if-statement, methods, program-entry-point

let's assume that I have two python scripts.
One of them is like:

```
def sum(x,y):
   return x+y 

def main():
  sum()

if __name__ = '__main__':
    main()
```

The other ones:

```
def sum(x+y):
    return x+y

  if __name__ == '__main__'':
       sum()
```

What is the difference between two option? Or is there any difference between write main method and then if statement and writing just if statement?
If you explain it, I will be grateful.
Thank you so much for your answers and time.

Comment: the second one bugs i think

Comment: `def sum(x+y):` is a syntax error.  You probably meant `def sum(x,y):` like the first one.

Comment: `main` has no special meaning in python. it really even a convention, different frameworks have different conventions.

Comment: the `if __name__ == "__main__": ...` idiom doesn't require or have anything to do with some method being named `main`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Second case has a syntax error, so assuming that you meant to do:

```
def sum(x, y):
    return x+y
```

Both cases will yield the same result however, you'll find that often, a function named main() encapsulates the program’s primary behavior, so it's something most programmers expect to see.
However there's nothing special about naming a function 'main()' or something else like 'primary_func()' the behavior will be the same.

However, there is 'something' special about naming a function 'sum()', the name 'sum' is a 'Built-In Namespace'. In general, it is considered bad practice to name functions using 'Built-In Namespaces'. These are reserved keywords/names that Python makes available for specific purposes.
Some examples of 'Built-In Namespaces' include: max, int, print, sum, and **name**.

You can use the following statement to list all the Built-In Namespaces:

```
print(dir(__builtins__))
```

You'll note that 'main' is not a Built-In Namespaces and therefore is safe to use.